# I want to change the color of TextButton using Functions

Tags: function, flutter, dart, button, colors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JgX8.png)

-> backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.color),

// Here i'm getting an error

Comment: `backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),` should display your button in red.

Answer (score 0):

you affect color without Colors

```
backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(color)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red), // Or whatever color
```

But if you need more control. Do like this

```
MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          (states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
              return greyColor;
            }else if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)) {
              return Colors.red;
            }
             // Check other stated too. As per your need
            return selectedPrimaryColor;
          },
        ),
```